# Idenify Pie chart legend name for use with onclick

Tags: javascript, c3.js

How would I pass the actual data legend name to the onclick alert. Apples or bananans in this example. [jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/laguna92651/pkzxg64d/2/)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30],
        ['data2', 120],
    ],          
    names: {
            data1: 'Apples',
            data2: 'Bananas',
            },  // legend names         
    type : 'pie',

    onclick: function (d, element) { 
    alert( d.ratio); 
    }        
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d.name gives you legend

Your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wu7ovtqn/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],          
        names: {
                data1: 'Apples',
                data2: 'Bananas',
                },  // legend names         
        type : 'pie',

        onclick: function (d, element) { 
                alert(d.name);// d.name is your legend
        }        
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had tried d.names, what a dummy. What if I had some custom data that was related  to the pie data. custom {data1:'Red',data2:'domestic'},

Comment: everything will be in d. try console.log(d) you can see what data is available in d

Comment: Yes, I see where d shows all of the obect data, but the                  custom: {
                data1: 'domestic',
                data2: 'imported',
                },                                                                                                  is separate data and does not show with console.log(d). I'm not even sure if the 'custom' data is in the correct location. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laguna92651/wu7ovtqn/1/)